# onChange doesnt work for my inputs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, onchange

I have 2 Inputs on these Inputs I have onChanges. Normally I work with ES6 Classes with a Constructur, but this time I have to work with functional components, and just don't know what I have made wrong. Everytime I type something in the inputs, it says the value of the input is still empty (if I want to read it out).

[my const-variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAe3h.png)

[my inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoETl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get the value typed in `e.target.value` and not just `e.value`